# SSRS Report Footer won't display

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, footer

- SQL Server 2014
- Report Builder 3.0

I have an invoice report which does not display the footer if the report is more than 2 pages long.

**Here's the problem:** The Globals!TotalPages is expecting 5 pages, but only 4 pages are actually printed so the footer remains hidden.

The hidden expression for the footer is this:

```
=iif(Globals!PageNumber=Globals!TotalPages,false,true)
```

Why would the TotalPages be greater than the actual pages? How do I fix it?

Comment: I've tried reading that paragraph like 5 times and still don't know what your issue is. You might want to try an outline or bullets.

Comment: And if you un-hide that textbox1, what is the value in it?

Comment: If you remove the hidden expression for the footer completely, what will happen?

Comment: @Dijkgraaf page 4 of 5 shows the value of textbox1 to be 35. But it's not page 5 of 5 so the footer didn't print.

Comment: Additional information, the last record of the dataset is printing on the next to the last page which means the last page never prints, therefore, I'm not getting the page footer.